# Array methods for nested list of class objects

Tags: arrays, list, system-verilog

I've recently transitioned from Specman/e to SystemVerilog and I'm struggling with the limitations of the array methods in SystemVerilog.
I have an array of class objects, which themselves have an array of class objects inside each one.
I want to check if the array has an item, whose sub-array has an item with a certain value.
In Specman this would be simple as so:

```
struct axi_beat_s {
   addr : int;
};

struct axi_trans_s {
   beat_list : list of axi_beat_s;
};

var axi_trans_list : list of axi_trans_s;
//Populate axi_trans_list, not shown here

//Check if the axi trans list has a trans with a beat with address 0
if (axi_trans_list.has(it.beat_list.has(it.addr == 0))) { //This is the line I want to replicate
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
};
```

What is the best way to achieve the same in SystemVerilog?
This is my attempt below, but it involves creating 2 temporary arrays, and several more lines of code. Is there an easier way of doing this?

```
class axi_beat_s;
    int addr;
endclass

class axi_trans_s;
    axi_beat_s beat_list [$];
endclass

axi_trans_s axi_trans_list [$];
//Populate axi_trans_list, not shown here

axi_trans_s axi_trans_list_temp [$];
axi_beat_s axi_beat_list_temp [$];

foreach(axi_trans_list[idx]) begin
    axi_beat_list_temp = axi_trans_list[idx].beat_list.find with (item.addr == 0);
    if (axi_beat_list_temp.size() > 0)
        axi_trans_list_temp.push_back(axi_trans_list[idx]);
    if (axi_trans_list_temp.size() > 0)
        $display("Found item with addr 0");
    else
        $display("Did not find item with addr 0");
end
```

Working example here:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/RFEk

Similarly Specman has a method 'all' which can be used to collect all matching items, similar to 'find' in SystemVerilog. But again, I can't find based on a nested class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the array reduction methods, not the `find` method.

The `find` method returns an array of the same type with the selected set of elements—it cannot be nested.  If you just want to get a true or false result, the array reduction methods return a single value and can be nested.

```
initial begin
 // populate list not shown here
  
  if (axi_trans_list.or() with (item.beat_list.or() with (item.addr==0)))
        $display("Found item with addr 0");
    else
        $display("Did not find item with addr 0");
end
```